# Find part of string in another string

Tags: regex, r, string

How do I find a part of a string in another string. Below you can find some sample data:

```
a <- c("23,45,24,67,91,10")
b <- c("as.01,as.23,as55,as69")
```

The objective is to find any substring of `a` in `b`. Thus this should return TRUE since 23 is present in `a` and in `b`. I already tried functions such as

```
charmatch
grepl
match
```

But all of these do not seem to fit my purpose. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If everything in `a` and `b` is just one string you don't need to use `c`...

Answer (score 5):

There may be an error in your inputs a and b:

```
a <- c("23","45","24","67","91","10")
b <- c("as.01","as.23","as55","as69")

> any(sapply(a, grepl, x=b))
[1] TRUE
```

Or only in your input a:

```
a <- c("23","45","24","67","91","10")
b <- c("as.01,as.23,as55,as69")

> any(sapply(a, grepl, x=b))
[1] TRUE
```

Or if no error:

```
> any(sapply(strsplit(a,',')[[1]], grepl, x=b))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: or if there is no error in the input, just do `a<-strsplit(a,",")[[1]]` before...

Comment: That is not what I need @ Colonel Beauvel. I need a function where I have two large strings and `a` subelement of a should be in `b`. Thus I do not have data like a <- c("23", "45", ...) but rather a <- c("23,45,...")

Comment: Thank you @CathG that was what I needed then. Then the answer of Beauvel works

Comment: @DavevanBrecht, you're welcome, I was writing a similar answer (except with the `strsplit` step) when ColonelBeauvel posted his so I just added the line, anyway, I'm pretty sure he would have added the line even without me ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid `*apply` loops and vectorize it using `gsub` in order to replace `,` to `|` and convert it to a valid regex expression.

```
grepl(gsub(",", "|", a, fixed = TRUE), b)
## [1] TRUE
```

This way, you also don't need to use `any` as it will return only one `TRUE` even if you have more than one matches, for example.

```
a <- "23,45,55,67,91,10"
b <- "as.01,as.23,as55,as69"

grepl(gsub(",", "|", a, fixed = TRUE), b)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Super nice, I was looking for some vectorization and you get it!